# I'm trying to install mongodb, and I've tried other version of mongodb from latest to older but it is not installing mongodb compass. this is error

Tags: mongodb, installation, windows-10, mongodb-compass

#Requires -Version 3.0
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Download and install latest version of MongoDB Compass.

.DESCRIPTION
A longer description.

.INPUTS
Description of objects that can be piped to the script

.OUTPUTS
Description of objects that are output by the script

.EXAMPLE
Example of how to run the script

.LINK
Links to further documentation

.NOTES
Detail on what the script does, if this is needed

Answer (score 0):

Please use this website to download and select your platform.

https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/compass

[Select Your system details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVcg3.png)